# Jedis Get Data: JedisConnectionFailureException iterating a section of code over long period of time

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, jedis

So I have a code that gets value from Redis using Jedis Client. But at a time, the Redis was at maximum connection and these exceptions were getting thrown:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
...
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
...
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
```

When I check an AppDynamics analysis of this scenario, I saw some iteration of some calls over a long period of time (1772 seconds). The calls are shown in the snips.

[image: First Snip (iteration of Thread:sleep and BinaryJedis:exists]

[image: Second Snip (iteration of Thread:sleep and BinaryJedis:exists]

Can anyone explain what's happening here? And why Jedis didn't stop after the Timeout setting (500ms)? Can I prevent this from happening for long?

This is what my Bean definitions for the Jedis look like:

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory" p:host-name="100.90.80.70" p:port="6382" p:timeout="500" p:use-pool="true" p:poolConfig-ref="jedisPoolConfig" p:database="3" />

<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxTotal" value="1000" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="500" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="10" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the AppDynamics output. I assume that's a cumulative view of Threads and their sleep times. So Threads get reused and so the sleep times add up. In some cases, a Thread gets a connection directly, without any waiting and in another call the Thread has to wait until the connection can be provided. The wait duration depends on when a connection becomes available, or the wait limit is hit.

#### Let's have a practical example:

Your screenshot shows a Thread, which waited `172ms`. Assuming the `sleep` is only called within the Jedis/Redis invocation path, the Thread waited `172ms` in total to get a connection.

Another Thread, which waited `530ms` looks to me as if the first attempt to get a connection wasn't successful (which explains the first `500ms`) and on a second attempt, it had to wait for `30ms`. It could also be that it waited 2x for `265ms`.

*Sidenote:*

1000+ connections could severely limit scalability. Spring Data Redis also supports other drivers which don't require pooling but work with fewer connections (see [Spring Data Redis Connectors](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:connectors:lettuce) and [here](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce)).